# Use a method of a class in another class

Tags: class, kotlin, methods

I have 2 kotlin files, each contains a class, first.kt contains `class First` and second.kt contains `class Second`.

In First, I have a method named "Create".

I wanna use the Create method in Second, but I don't want to create an instance of First.

I'm new in kotlin, I want something like static methods in c#

Comment: did my answer work for you? :)

Comment: great to hear that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `companion object` for that. Then import the method from `First` like this

> First.kt

```
class First {

    companion object {
        fun create() {

            println("Hello from create")
        }
    }
}
```

> Second.kt

```
import First.Companion.create

class Second {

    fun getData() {
        create()
    }
}
```